# How do I declare a static const char array in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, static, unsigned-char

I need to convert following code to Swift

```
static const char gSalt[] =
    {
        (unsigned char)0xf4, (unsigned char)0x28, (unsigned char)0x32, (unsigned char)0xab,
        (unsigned char)0x4b, (unsigned char)0xa1, (unsigned char)0xcc, (unsigned char)0x43
    };
```

Comment: Good luck. Do you have a question?

Comment: where have you been stuck at during the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, a `UInt8` is the corresponding type to C's *unsigned char*, so this would create a constant array of `UInt8` values:

```
let gSalt:[UInt8] = [0xf4, 0x28, 0x32, 0xab, 0x4b, 0xa1, 0xcc, 0x43]
```

In Swift, you should just declare this in whatever scope you need it.  If it is only needed by the methods of a single class, then declare this in that class.  If you need it globally, then declare it outside of any class.